# Why am I getting a Missing $ inserted error with \begin{array}?

Tags: math-mode

Why am getting the error, `! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ \begin{array}{l}` with this code?

```
\documentclass[]{report}   % list options between brackets
\usepackage{}              % list packages between braces
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{E:/College/IIST/SEM II/Subjects/Power Electronics and PS/Assginments/3 ph FEC/Report/}}
%\graphicspath{{./figs/}}
   \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathleft}{\@fleqntrue\@mathmargin0pt}
\newcommand{\mathcenter}{\@fleqnfalse}
\makeatother

% type user-defined commands here

\begin{document}


\newpage
\chapter{Calculations}                   % chapter 2
\section{FEC}                               % section 2.1
\subsection{Inductor Design}         % subsection 2.1.1

\mathleft
\begin{array}{l}We\see,\\
\overrightarrow{V_{inv}\ }=\overrightarrow{V_g}+\overrightarrow{V_{Ls}}\\
\overrightarrow{V_{AB,\ pk}\ }=\overrightarrow{V_{g,\ pk}}+wL_s.\overrightarrow{\ I_{g,pk}}\\
Squaring\ on\ both\ sides,\\
V_{AB,\ pk}^{\ 2}\ =\ V_{g,\ pk}^{\ 2}\ +\ \left(wL_s.I_{g,\ pk}^{\ }\right)^2\\
∴\ L_s=\ \sqrt{\frac{\left(V_{AB,\ pk}^{\ 2}-V_{g,\ pk}^{\ 2}\right)}{\left(wL_s.I_{g,\ pk}^{\ }\right)^2}}\\
\ \ \ L_s\ =\ \sqrt{\frac{325^2-325.269^2}{\left(2\pi\cdot50\cdot9.41136\right)^2}}\\
∴\ L_s=\ 4.47322\ mH\\
\\
\\
\\
\end{array}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). What is your question. Also please make you code compileable and provide a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and loading all/only necessary packages.

Comment: The `array` environment should be used inside math mode, this is what the error in your question's title mean.

Comment: @KersouMan Want to make that an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're getting this error message because `array` environments *must* occur in math mode.

I would like to suggest that you employ an `align*` environment and perform alignment on the `=` symbols instead of employing an `array` environment. (The `align*` environment is provided by the `amsmath` package.) I'd also use `\vec{V}` rather than the unwieldy `\longrightarrow` expressions, I'd use `\cdot` rather than `.` ("dot") to indicate multiplication, and I'd omit the `\left` and `\right` auto-sizing directives they do nothing except mess up the horizontal alignment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{amssymb} % for "\therefore" macro
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "align*" environment
\usepackage[group-digits=false]{siunitx} % for "\qty" macdro
\begin{document}

\noindent
We see
\begin{align*}
\vec{V}_{\mathit{inv}} &=\vec{V}_g+\vec{V}_{Ls}\\
\vec{V}_{\!AB,pk} &=\vec{V}_{g,pk}+wL_s\cdot\vec{I}_{g,pk}\\
\intertext{Squaring on both sides,}
V_{\!AB,pk}^{2} &= V_{g,pk}^{2} + (wL_s\cdot I_{g,pk})^2 \\ % why no cross-product term??
\therefore
L_s &= \sqrt{\frac{(V_{\!AB,pk}^{2}-V_{g,pk}^{2})}{(w\cdot I_{g,pk})^2}}\\
    &= \sqrt{\frac{325^2-325.269^2}{(2\pi\cdot50\cdot9.41136)^2}}\\
    &= \qty{4.47322}{mH}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved it.

Comment: @User - You're most welcome. If you believe that this answer fully solved your query, feel free to "accept" the answr by clicking on the checkmark symbol. ;-)